# Php password_verify codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have little problem with password_verify.
I used codeigniter 3 for study.

I have user model

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function createUser($args): int
    {
        $query = $this->db->insert('user', $args);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
        
    }

    public function getUser(string $email): array
    {
        $query = $this->db->get_where('user',array('email'=> $email));
        return $query->row_array();
    }

}
```

User Controller

```
<?php


class UserController extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $this->load->helper('url_helper');
    }
    public function profile()
    {

        $data['user'] = $this->user_model->getUser($_POST['email']);
        $hash = $data['user']['password'];

        if(password_verify($_POST['password'],$hash)){
            echo "success";
        }else{
            echo "failed";
        }
        $this->load->view('templates/header');

        $this->load->view('pages/profileUser',$data);
        
    }
```

If I used in controller static password it's work, if I get hash password by DB function password_verify not work.

Thank you for support,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As php.net [explains](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-verify.php) `password_verify()` verifies passwords that are created via `password_hash()`.

If you use a sha256-hash you can better hash the users input and compare with the password of the DB query like so:

```
$password = $this->input->post('password');
if(hash('sha256', $password) == $hash) {
 echo 'success';
} else {
 echo 'failed';
}
```

Better way in my opinion is to check the password on the fly in the query like so:

```
$user_query = $this->db->get_where('users', array('email' => $email, 'password' => hash('sha256', $password));
if($user_query->num_rows() == 0) {
 print 'failed';
} else {
 print 'success';
 $user = $user_query->row_array();
 ...
}
```

BTW: It is better to use CodeIgniters $this->input->post('password') as it does the security filtering for you.